# Why does "foo".class === String return false?

Tags: ruby, string, boolean, equality

I became curious when this didn't work as I expected:

```
var = "foo"
case var.class
when String
  puts "bar"
else
  puts "baz"
=> "baz"
```

I understand that the case statement is using `===`, but I don't understand what `===` does. The docs say...

> Case Equality – For class Object, effectively the same as calling #==,
>   but typically overridden by descendants to provide meaningful
>   semantics in case statements.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

Does this mean that `===` in Class (or one of its modules) overrides `===` in Object? I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`===` is overridden for `Class` objects (and more generally, [`Module` objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)) to mean "is the right-hand side an instance of the left-hand side".

For instance:

```
>> String === ""
=> true
>> Class === String
=> true
```

This is unintuitive, but it's true. It does, however, make what you're trying to do even shorter:

```
var = "foo"
case var
when String
  puts "bar"
else
  puts "baz"
end
# outputs "bar", since String === "foo"
```

Here's why your attempt didn't work: Ruby evaluates `String === String`, which is false, since the `String` class is not itself a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with `case equality` here. Here, it is overridden by descendants to provide meaningful semantics. In this case, `Module` overrides it.

> Case Equality — Returns true if an object is an instance of a module or one of the module's descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in case statements to classify objects by class.

In modules, `===` acts like Ruby's `is_a?` method.

In your case, it returns false because `"Foo".class` isn't an instance of the string class.

```
"Foo".class.is_a?(String)
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how the case equivalence operator `===` is implemented for classes.  Use the object, not the object.class

```
var = "foo"
case var
when String
  puts "bar"
else
  puts "baz"
=> "bar"
```